# Using Sqlite, Python 2.7 and Spatialite?

Tags: python, sql, spatialite, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to spatially enable my sqlite database:

```
import sqlite3
db = r'c:\temp\mydata.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(r"SELECT load_extension("<path>\libspatialite-4.dll");")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
del conn
```

Python just stops working when I run this code.  It doesn't crash in windows 7 x64, it just closes.  It's very strange.  No error is raised.

When I run the commands directly from python.exe in the command propmpt, I see python crashing:
[image: spatialite crashing python]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are using a 32 bit version of python. Are you definitely using a 32 bit version of spatialite?

Comment: Can you use try catch for more details ?

Comment: @BradHards - Yes I'm using a 32-bit version of spatialite.

Comment: What are the details of your binaries?  Are you using Arc built python and/or spatialite?  How new is the spatialite build?  Are spatialites dependencies available(geos, iconv, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of `sqlite3.dll` included with Python doesn't seem to want to play nice with Spatialite. The only thing I could get to work (short of compiling everything from source) was:

1. Download [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) (or [cyqlite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cyqlite/) - a recompile of SQLite for Windows with some handy features enabled, such as R-Tree so you can do spaital indexes) i.e. `sqlite-dll-win32-x86-[version].zip`
2. Download [mod_spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) (Windows binaries are in the pink box at the bottom of the page) i.e. `mod_spatialite-[version]-win-x86.7z`
3. Unzip **first** *SQLite/cyqlite* **then** *mod_spatialite* into the **same folder** (overwrite if there are any conflicts)
4. Add this folder to your system Path
5. Rename the `sqlite3.dll` that is in your Python DLLs directory, to something like `sqlite3_old.dll`, so that Python will use the new one on your path

See [this blog post](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/python-and-spatialite-32-bit-on-64-bit-windows/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

this thread may be a bit old - but i ran into a somewhat similar issue a couple of months back

i think this post was also related - [Sqlite, Python 2.7 and Spatialite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85674/sqlite-python-2-7-and-spatialite)

i ended up finding another build of libspatialite-4.dll here http://latuviitta.org/documents/Spatialite_4.0_test_with_jre_1.6.zip
although it is also labeled as 'test'...

after placing this build of libspatialite-4 in my python27/DLLs, it seemed to work.

Comment: Oops- I think this was the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667981/getting-a-working-spatialite-sqlite-system-for-x64-c-sharp I meant to refer to above. Or the answer to that post anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please:

```
cur.execute(r'SELECT load_extension("<path>\libspatialite-4.dll");')
```

instead of your `cur.execute` line

And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590599/sqlite-load-extension-fail-for-spatialite-in-python), also. They solved by putting all the dlls in the System32 folder even on a Windows 7 - 64 bits.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work as well

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have the library name correct?

For Python 2.7 and Spatialite 4 that are shipped with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 I have to do the following:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
db.enable_load_extension(True)
db.load_extension('spatialite400x.dll')
```

I believe that `db.load_extension` and executing the function in SQL should have the same effect, but I do always use `load_extension`.

Comment: When try using this code, I get sqlite3.OperationalError: The specified module could not be found.  I do have ArcGIS 10.2.1 installed btw.

Comment: I also tried using the full path to the ArcGIS Bin folder as well.

Comment: @josh1234 Well you do have a slightly newer version than I do (My python is 2.7.3). The library should be located in the ArcGIS bin directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin. It may be named something other than spatialite400x.dll in 10.2.1.

Comment: hmm, I looked in the file location, and the file is the same.